# Is it possible to transfer control of a program between GDB sessions?

Tags: c++, gdb

I've got a GDB session with a c++ program process loaded. I'd like to transfer it to another GDB session on the same machine with a different interface for easier debugging. Is it possible to detach the process without it continuing to run so that I can attach it in the other GDB session?

Comment: Can you easily explain why you don't simply start your session with the 'easier to use' gdb?

Comment: To get this GDB session, did you use attach?  (See debugging aleady running process.)

Comment: The GDB session is spawned by the program under debug.

Comment: Did you consider renaming the 'easier-to-use' gdb such that the spawned session will launch it instead of current contents of "/usr/local/bin/gdb"?  It need not be a permanent change, just a small script to launch your app then restore the usual gdb.  (Not sure I can recommend this, but I have seen it done.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to detach the process without it continuing to run so
>   that I can attach it in the other GDB session?

I like your question, but let me suggest an alternate approach that I find easy to use.

A simple function (such as the following) can hold any thread as long as it takes to attach your debugger.  Also, you can set the parkFlag using -D options to make and conditional compilation and default the settings to your liking.

```
bool parkFlag = true;
void park()
{
   while(parkFlag)     // pause thread for some time
      std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
}
```

Thus, for your 'more convenient' debug session,  invoke park just after main.

Now start up the 'more convenient' debugger, attach, set some breakpoints, then clear the parkFlag.

Comment: If the OP could rebuild his program, he could easily start debugging it with the "right" GDB. The problem likely is that the state of the already-running process is important to preserve.

Comment: @EmployedRussian   Agreed. My imagination fails me.  I did not ask if this was his 'real' question. I assumed there was a reason he was starting with the 'less convenient gdb'.  It does suggests to me that maybe his real question is more 'how can I do the same thing in this 'more convenient' gdb.  I thought ddd can do anything gdb can?  Generally, I run gdb inside of emacs, and only occasionally do I have to handle things such as: task output is meant for gnome-terminal (or terminator) and does not work on emacs input/output redirect.

Comment: The program under debug spawns the GDB session and there is no main() to loop in, as the program debugged is a fork of the main process so I would have to add it there. I've tried this and it should work in principle, it was just hard to specify under which conditions to run the loop.  I'd rather modify the existing program as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to detach the process without it continuing to run so that I can attach it in the other GDB session?

You could do `(gdb) signal SIGSTOP` to stop the current process, but GDB will automatically resume the process on `detach` command.

What may work is not `detach`ing the process, but killing the GDB itself with `kill -9`. Even then, the kernel may decide to resume the process anyway when it is no longer being `ptrace`d.

Comment: So you don't think it's possible?

Comment: I think it *may* work with `kill -9 $gdb`, but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 0):

> The GDB session is spawned by the program under debug

I do not know enough about how your program spawns the gdb session.
But you might experiment with creating an alias (line 6) prior to your test run.

```
 1 dmn@C5:~$ which gdb
 2 /usr/local/bin/gdb
 3 dmn@C5:~$ which ddd
 4 /usr/bin/ddd
 5 dmn@C5:~$ 
 6 dmn@C5:~$ alias gdb='ddd'
 7 dmn@C5:~$ 
 8 dmn@C5:~$ which gdb
 9 /usr/local/bin/gdb
10 dmn@C5:~$ which ddd
11 /usr/bin/ddd
12 dmn@C5:~$ 
13 dmn@C5:~$ gdb
14 dmn@C5:~$ ---command to start your program---
```

On my ubuntu system, line 13 invokes the alias.

---

From my embedded systems background, we could grep through the executable binary file, and any string we found (such as 'gdb') we could hex edit to something else (maybe 'ddd').

Not recommending it as there are more proper 'patch' approaches ... but you are just trying out the idea 'can an alias 'redirect' a spawn'.

Perhaps this is idea is 'how do you patch an existing executable?' (i.e. without rebuilding it.